# Issue updating wall dimensions, materialis, etc

Tags: aframe, archilogic, 3d.io

Right now I am having issues updating the dimensions/materials of walls.

The A-Scene in question is one that i am hosting(not hosted on 3d.io website/platform) that was obtained via uploading a 2d floorplan.

Here is a snippet from my code. Basically, this snippet appears to be updating the data of the walls effectively, changing the height to 1 meter. But, the changes are not being reflected visually.

```
let walls = document.querySelectorAll('[io3d-wall]')

for(let i = 0; i<walls.length; i ++){
   walls[i].components['io3d-wall'].data.h = 1
   walls[i].components['io3d-wall'].update()
}
```

If you have any notions as to why I am experiencing this issue please share.

Thank You

Kashi Rana Halma
Blockvue

Answer (score 0):

use standard A-frame syntax

```
let walls = document.querySelectorAll('[io3d-wall]')

for(let i = 0; i<walls.length; i ++){
  walls[i].setAttribute('io3d-wall', {h: 1})
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Frederic. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Frederic, again, thank you for your reply. Despite implementing your approach I am still getting the same results. Here is a video that illustrates my issues. Please take a look at the video. I hope it gives you a clue as to the cause of my issue. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTWnt_JZe6k&feature=youtu.be

Comment: you need to un-bake the model first in the editor to edit it
https://docs.archilogic.com/en/3d-editor/lighting/